# Load error when running rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.1

Everything works, but when I run rails console I get this error

```
> rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
load error: /home/andreas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/.irbrc
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
    /home/andreas/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
```

After the error the console opens and can be used.

Here's the 41th line and surroundings in the .irbrc file.

```
39 # Calculate the ruby string.
40 rvm_ruby_string = ENV["rvm_ruby_string"] ||
41 (ENV['GEM_HOME'] && ENV['GEM_HOME'].split(/\//).last.split(/@/).first) ||
42 ("#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}" rescue nil) ||
43 (RUBY_DESCRIPTION.split(" ")[1].sub('p', '-p') rescue nil ) ||
44 (`ruby -v` || '').split(" ")[1].sub('p', '-p')
```

I get these results when testing in the console

```
irb(main):008:0> ENV['GEM_HOME']
=> ""
irb(main):009:0> ENV['GEM_HOME'].split(/\//).last
=> nil
```

If I run irb outside the rails application, I get

```
2.1.1 :001 > ENV['GEM_HOME']
 => "/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1" 
2.1.1 :002 > ENV['GEM_HOME'].split(/\//).last
 => "ruby-2.1.1"
```

Do you know why the environment variable is blank in the rails application?

Comment: Can you give us more details about your stack? I take you're running on a flavour of Linux -- how is it setup?

Comment: I've seen this too - running bundle exec rails c produced the error but not bin/rails c. I've not had a chance to dig further. Perhaps bundler messing with the gem environment in a way that confuses rvm?

Comment: @RichPeck It's newly updated ubuntu 14.04, rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.1. All was updated from the previous version.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I get the error with all possible command (bin/rails , bundle exec rails c and rails c). I am guessing that rails GEM_HOME can be different than the global GEM_HOME, and when rails c is run the rails GEM_HOME is in use.

Comment: This is probably because something happened with your rvm environment. Something just happened with mine so I am reinstalling rvm since I had 10GB of out of date ruby versions on there anyway.

Comment: I encountered this after I'd updated spring 1.2.0 to 1.3.x. I ran `spring binstub` and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you encounter this problem **you should restart you computer**. If that does not fix it read on.

The bin/spring file sets ENV["GEM_HOME"] to a blank string

bin/spring

```
11 ENV["GEM_PATH"] = ([Bundler.bundle_path.to_s] + Gem.path).join(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
12 ENV["GEM_HOME"] = ""
13 Gem.paths = ENV
```

This crashes when running rails console because in line 41

```
ENV['GEM_HOME'].split(/\//).last
```

returns nil if `ENV['GEM_HOME']` is blank

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/.irbrc

```
39 # Calculate the ruby string.
40 rvm_ruby_string = ENV["rvm_ruby_string"] ||
41 (ENV['GEM_HOME'] && ENV['GEM_HOME'].split(/\//).last.split(/@/).first) ||
42 ("#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}" rescue nil) ||
43 (RUBY_DESCRIPTION.split(" ")[1].sub('p', '-p') rescue nil ) ||
44 (`ruby -v` || '').split(" ")[1].sub('p', '-p')
```

rvm uses the string to set the prompt message in the console.
If you change line 12 in bin/spring to

```
ENV["GEM_HOME"] = "Spring is great!"
```

You get this nice prompt

```
bin/rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
Spring is great! :001 >
```

I don't really understand why `ENV["GEM_HOME"]` is set to a blank string. So, I just change this to get rid of the error. I have posted an issue on the spring github page.

### Beware!

Any changes to the bin/spring file gets overwritten when you run the `spring binstub` command

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem, and I solved it by `spring stop`. I think there is no need to restart the computer. What you should do is to restart spring.

Comment: In my case I had to restart the computer I tried `spring stop`, but I still had the error

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved my problem:

- find the current ruby version

> ruby -v

example:

> ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

- remove this version

> rvm remove 2.1.2

- install again

> rvm install 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to specify a gemset with

```
rvm gemset use YourGemset
```

I find it's a good idea to use a separate gemset for each project. Then place the name of that project's gemset in a file named `.ruby-gemset` in the root of your project. See https://rvm.io/workflow/projects for more info.