# RVM forgets default gemset when shell reloaded

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, irb

After I upgrade my RVM, Ruby and Rails I get this error (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):

```
☁  ~  irb
load error: /home/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
    /home/patrick/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /home/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /home/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc:11:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `load'
    /home/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `run_config'
    /home/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:19:in `setup'
irb(main):001:0>
```

And for fix that, I need to run the command below every time:

```
rvm gemset use default --default
```

---

**I tried..**

- create other gemset and set `--default`, but doesn't
- reinstall rvm, but doesn't
- reinstall ruby, but doesn't
- reinstall rails, but doesn't

---

**ruby, rails, rvm and gem --version**

```
☁  ~  ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
☁  ~  rails --version
Rails 4.1.2.rc1
☁  ~  rvm --version
rvm 1.25.27 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
☁  ~  gem --version
2.2.2
☁  ~
```

---

**$GEM_HOME**

```
/home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4
```

---

**$GEM_PATH**

```
/home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4:/home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
```

---

**$PATH**

```
/home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/bin:
/home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:
/home/patrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/home/patrick/.rvm/bin:
/home/patrick/.rvm/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/home/patrick/.rvm/bin
```

---

**.zshrc (oh-my-zsh)**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

---

If you need more information, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Problem is *NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass*..

Comment: Here is your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215454/load-error-when-running-rails-console

Comment: Here is a [bug ticket](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2529) and the [patch is here](https://github.com/ghiculescu/rvm/commit/4c9feae005d8d595e2322998d4612e76246198c7)..

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes!? But I just type `irb`... sooooo?