# rails console error: 'load error' 'NoMethodError'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I installed rails, but when I try to run $rails console I get an error. Can anybody tell me what should I do?(I know similar questions have been asked before, but I still don't know what exactly should I do.) If that helps, I have ubuntu 13.10, ruby 2.1.2, rails 4.1.1. The error is pretty long, this is how it starts:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
load error: /home/u12/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
    /home/u12/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/u12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
```

Comment: Paste line 45 of .irbrc Looks like there's an empty string trying to be splitted. Let's find which one is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try:

```
rvm get stable
```

If it doesn't work:

As stated in this previous thread:

[Load error when running rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215454/load-error-when-running-rails-console)

The problem might be that the ENV['GEM_HOME'] is nil.

Spring seems to be the problem and a small incompatibility with rvm.

Just change the env variable to a blank string.

If you encounter this problem you should restart you computer. If that does not fix it read on.

The bin/spring file sets ENV["GEM_HOME"] to a non blank string

bin/spring

```
11 ENV["GEM_PATH"] = ([Bundler.bundle_path.to_s] + Gem.path).join(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
12 ENV["GEM_HOME"] = "spring"
13 Gem.paths = ENV
```

Comment: I have this same issue and restarted my computer and I'm still getting the error. I changed the bin/spring ENV variable in my rails project and I still get the error.

Comment: Paste line    45 of .irbrc    /home/u12/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: Thank you, but changing "" to "spring" didn't help. Here is line 45:  path.split(/\//).last.split(/@/).first

Comment: Search for this path variable and find why is empty. path.split is failing because of that.

Comment: I think it's here, but I don't really understand that: 

# Calculate the ruby string.
rvm_ruby_string = ENV["rvm_ruby_string"] ||
  (
    ENV['GEM_HOME'] &&
    path = ( File.realpath(ENV['GEM_HOME'].to_s) rescue nil ) &&
    ( path = $1 if path =~ /(.+)\/$/ ; true ) &&
    path.split(/\//).last.split(/@/).first
  ) ||

Comment: 1) do: $rvm get stable 2) paste those lines in the question properly formated. :)

Comment: I did rvm get stable and the irbrc.rb file has changed... So those lines aren't even there anymore and the error is different. I can run the console now.                                                                             

Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
2.1.2 :001 >

                                                                                   Is it okay if there is 2.1.2 instead of irb(main) or would that be a different thing?

Comment: (sorry for unproperly formated text... I don't know how to type code in comments.)

Comment: So you say that the problem is solved? And now you have a different one?

Comment: I think it is. (But I have an example of how it should be and there is irb(main) and I don't have that. That's why I'm asking if you know if that needs to be there or not.) But yes, a new one appears later when I try subject = Subject.new and there is an Mysql2 error, but I guess this is a different thing.

Comment: The prompt may change depending on the rails/ruby version. Mine is: 2.1.2 :001 > |

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of your files tries to call the split method on a variable that is nil instead of a string. You should either check that it's actually a string before calling split, or use the to_s method to make sure it never raise an exeception.